# Texture vs storage for FBO depth buffer

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Assuming the device support the GL_OES_depth_texture extension, is there any difference in terms of performance or memory consumption in attaching a storage or a texture to a FBO ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your post is tagged with OpenGLES 2.0 which most likely means you're talking about mobile.

Many Android mobile GPUs and all iOS GPUs are based on Tile Based Deferred Renderers - in this design, the rendering is all done to small (e.g. 32x32) tiles using special fast on-chip memory. In a typical rendering pass, with correct calls to glClear and glDiscardFramebufferEXT, there's no need for the device to ever have to copy depth buffer out from the on-chip memory into storage.

However, if you're using a depth texture, then this copy is unavoidable. The cost of transferring a screen-sized depth texture from on-chip memory into a texture is significant. However, I'd expect the rendering costs of your draw calls during the render pass to be unaffected.

In terms of memory usage, it's a bit more speculative. It's possible that a clever driver might not need to allocate any memory at all for a depth buffer on a TBDR GPU if you're not using a depth texture and you're using glClear and glDiscardFramebufferEXT correctly because at no point does your depth buffer have to be backed by any storage. Whether drivers actually do that is internal to the driver's implementation and you would have to ask the driver authors (Apple/Imagination Technologies/ARM, etc).

Finally, it may be the case that the depth buffer format has to undergo some reconfiguration to be usable as a depth texture which could mean it uses more memory and affect efficiency. I think that's unlikely though.

TLDR: Don't use a depth texture unless you actually need to, but if you do need one, then I don't think it will impact your rendering performance too much. The main cost is in the bandwidth of copying the depth data about.

Comment: Many thanks :) I will therefore make readable depth buffer an option and not a default in my rendering engine.